# MouseBinding overrides EventBindings in style

Tags: wpf, event-handling, styles, inputbinding

I created a named style on an image, and in the style I set an EventBinding for the MouseDown event to a handler at the ResourceDictionary's code-behind, it worked good.
When I use the image as the following:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}" x:Key="ImageStyle">
    <EventSetter Event="MouseDown" Handler="Image_MouseDown"/>
</Style>
<!---->
<Image Style="{StaticResource ImageStyle}">
    <Image.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Command="Save" MouseAction="LeftClick"/>
    </Image.InputBindings>
</Image>
```

It causes the styled MouseDown eventbinding not to work.

Comment: Can you post the code of your style, or its relevant part?

Comment: ok, the EventBinding is only in the style, the InputBinding is only in the Image definition as above

Comment: can you post the code? that will make things much easier... you can edit your post...

Comment: OK, if that makes you happy then of course, there is no better thing than making someone happy.
I've edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say without the style code, but I suppose you're defining `InputBindings` property in that style, then the `Image` setting just override it. Whatever you set in the actual element XAML overrides whatever you define in that element's style.

If that's the case, there's no easy way to merge style properties with the actual properties.

HTH.